# How to get commented string using regular expression in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get commented strings in my code using regular expression in php.

Let's say I have following string.

```
$string = "
   ///<summary>
   ///test
   ///</summary>
";
```

I use preg_match_all for regular expression function.

when I put $string to preg_match_all, it displays

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'string' in /home/document/public_html/test.php on line 10

I guess it is because I have modifiers(/) in $string.

How do I get around this?

Actual Code

```
$string = "
///<summary
///aaa
///</summary>
";

$pattern = "/\/\/\/<summary>\/\/\/.*\/\/\/</summary";

preg_match($pattern,$a,$match);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don’t have to use `/` as delimiters. So try this:

```
$pattern = '~///<summary>\s*///.*///</summary>~s';
```

Comment: Can PHP do the common Perl idom "`m(patern)`"?

Comment: @Brad Gilbert: See http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use a `preg_match_all` and do

```
/\/\/\/.*/
```

instead.  That would match all lines that have `///` at the beginning